# Apache2 user file access mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

Recently our school is having to move our online storage from an offsite provider to a server within our school.  But we will still be using their server for our online courses, just the files will be moved.

What I would like is when the student is logged into the offsite server and they click on a link that is directing them to a file on our server (i.e. assignment.pdf) they will then be presented with a login window before they can get the file.  And their session will be remembered.

I have setup a SUSE11 server with Apache2 and have a working login system that uses php and mysql but it simply loads a php file that gives me a list of files they can download.  Our dean wants the server to just give them the file they clicked on.

I have tried to use mod_rewrite but I keep failing at every attempt.
Our Idea was to have the server redirect (through mod_rewrite) the students request to a login.php file and check the session to see if they have already logged in, then they have to either login to access their file or if they already have logged in redirect them to the file they requested.  We seem to keep getting infinite loopbacks or the file is never found.

I have a virtual host conf file created in the virtual.d folder and I have been storing the rewrite statements there.  I assume that this is the correct location.

Could someone please help?
I am an old Netware user (20 years) moving to an all Linux enviroment it hasn’t been easy.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: FYI, when you indent four spaces on StackOverflow, your text is treated as code and presented `like this`.  Consult the [markdown guide](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information.  Cheers~

Comment: You can pipe the referer with RedirectMatch more under http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_alias.html

Comment: thx andrew for making it readable!